# The identity column must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, decimal, or numeric with a scale of 0, and the column must not be nullable

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

Using Visual Studio 2012 (VS2012) with SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) I am receiving this error after attaching the database project to StarTeam 2009 R2 (I was previously working this project with no source control). The StarTeam 2009 R2 integration client for VS2012 has been installed for multiple weeks, but since putting the solution on the source control server, Visual Studio's performance has been seriously reduced (waiting 20-40 seconds for context menu to popup) and now this error which makes no sense to me.

```
SQL71518: The identity column '[Domain\Login].[temp#].[Id]' must be of data type int,
bigint, smallint, tinyint, decimal, or numeric with a scale of 0, and the column must
not be nullable.
```

As far as I can tell, there is nothing syntactically wrong with this code - though I may agree with lots of other issues...

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Domain\Login].[temp#]
(
    [Code]        VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [Description] VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [Id]          INT           IDENTITY(1, 1)  NOT NULL
)
```

Any idea why the `[Id]` column is flagged with Error SQL71518? The column is of datatype `int` and is non-nullable, which meets the requirements mentioned in the error message.

*This code was inherited from an outside vendor, who stopped supporting their product. Since the product was considered important to my company, they arranged to get the source code so we could support it ourselves. I'm relatively new to this particular project and the whole team knows that it has serious flaws; but we've not received the budget necessary to upgrade the code and fix all the design issues - only to perform some "minor" modifications, which should be unrelated to the above error. As such I'd ignore this error, but it is interfering with the VS2012 Database Schema Comparison utility.*

**Edit 1**

SSDT for VS 2012 is already at 11.1.50730.0

```
SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.50730.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
```

Comment: I just created that schema on a test system and the code you provided to create the table works with no issue.

Comment: Agree the code posted would not produce the error posted.   The error must be caused by something else not mentioned in the question.  Or the error lies in StarTeam, whatever that is.   Sounds like a third-party client, in which case this is not a programming question.

Comment: @MitchWheat - the schema name was obfuscated to hide the identity of the guilty. But the original was in that format.

Comment: @SeanLange - I agree with your assessment. Personally, I think the table was erroneously created by someone logged in with the application's resource account and just got carried along with the rest of the code...  Unfortunately, it would take me much too long to verify this guess and get approval to drop it. :(

Comment: @Keith - There are worse source control systems than StarTeam. For instance, the original Visual Source Safe! When I first started using StarTeam it was a massive improvement. But that was years ago, since then I've also enjoyed working with better systems. But I'm stuck using the system that this project's team has chosen to use.

Comment: @TabAlleman - you're probably right, I just wish I knew specifically what was causing the problem and how to correct it.

Comment: @Zarepheth Yes SourceSafe is even worse! Just the mention of it gives me chills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table had a single record, so I modified the table design via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to make the identity column the first column in the list. Using SSMS, the table's data was retained during the modification. I'm not sure if Visual Studio would have preserved the table - especially since the Schema Comparison utility was out of commission due to the error.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Domain\Login].[temp#] (
    [commodity_id] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [code]         VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [name]         VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
);
```

Whatever is going on with Visual Studio 2012 and SSDT, this seems to have corrected the error -- at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

The version of SSDT that comes with Visual Studio 2012 is very outdated, maybe that is why it works for everyone else?

Get a newer version of SSDT (2013 or 2015) and it should work - you don't have to pay for licenses you can get the one that comes with visual studio express or community.

ed

Comment: That's the thing about working for a large corporation, employees don't always have full control over their choice of tools. At this time, VS 2012 is the most recent one supported by the StarTeam 2009 R2 Integration client. Next week I may be able to use a newer version of VS as StarTeam will be upgraded to 2014.

Comment: Cool, let us know if upgrading doesn't fix it and I understand your pain and constraints I have been there with you 100% :)

Comment: Note that Microsoft releases updates for SSDT in Visual Studio.  The latest RTM (i.e. non-Preview) version of SSDT was released in July 2015, and that update is available for Visual Studio 2012.  Look here for the download: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt204009.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please try updating to the latest version of SSDT for Visual Studio 2012.  The download is available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt204009.aspx

I've tried reproducing the problem as described using the latest version of SSDT, but I didn't encounter this behavior.  If you continue to experience this problem even using the latest version of SSDT for Visual Studio 2012, I would suggest filing a Connect issue at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx using the category "Developer Tools (SSDT, BIDS, etc.)".